# Why are my VMWare 5 virtual machines not booting when converted over to Microsoft Hyper-V 2012r2?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a Dell VMWare 5.x environment, but am experimenting with Microsoft Hyper-V (server 2012r2 64).  I am using the Microsoft converter utility to move these vm's, which completes fine but the resulting Hyper-V VM does not boot.   It shows the Hyper-V logo, then sits at a black screen with a flashing cursor.

On one example Dell machine - an R900 running Hyper-V, I am able to successfully create a NEW vm and install Windows Server 2012r2.  It boots up fine, and I am able to connect to it.    SO, I believe that would eliminate any hardware limitations, correct?

I have read online, about possibly needing to fix the MBR or possibly hack/replace the HAL.  Is this normal, or should there be a cleaner way to convert/move these vm's over to HyperV?

Two examples of VMs I have tried: Windows Server 2008r2 and Server 2012r2 64.   I am using MVMC v 3 (latest at the moment off their site)

--

UPDATE:

I tried using a 2008 boot disk (repair function) and it recognizes my OS (though it looks like it's on the 'd' drive).   Researching, I found [advice](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jonjor/archive/2011/10/04/vm-does-not-boot-following-p2v-or-disk2vhd.aspx) to run "bootrec /fixmbr" and some other similar commands and it worked!   HOWEVER, I do not like this solution for a production machine.   It would be nice to understand and have a solution to covert these without having to 'fixmbr'?

Comment: You haven't told us the most critical part: what is the OS of the guests?

Comment: The HAL issue is only for XP/2003 and older. Anything newer doesn't have that issue. What OS are the guests? What version of MVMC did you use?

Comment: I updated above

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See this question, which also discusses some of this: [Hyper-V VM doesn't boot off SCSI hard drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/629245/hyper-v-vm-doesnt-boot-off-scsi-hard-drive)

I would check your drive configuration in Hyper-V. Maybe, if there's more than one drive, it's trying to boot to the wrong one. EDIT: No BISO, check the config of the Hyper-V Guest to ensure the proper drive is selected as the boot drive.

Additionally, if your Hyper-V VMs are version 1, they don't support boot from SCSI, something that ESXi 5.x may have configured for those machines by default. Ensure your boot drive is connected as an IDE drive and see what happens then, or upgrade the VM to guest version 2 if you can.

Like other commenters, it's hard to say without other info, but (from my experience) these seem to be the most common issues with booting after a cutover. Good luck.

Comment: 1. You can't boot into the BIOS on a Hyper-V VM, it just doesn't work that way. 2. If a boot disk isn't found, it says "No Operating System was Loaded", usually with a few more details. 3. The "SCSI" bus on Hyper-V has nothing to do with SCSI, and the Converter understands this. If he had configured the VMs manually this could be an issue, though he'd still get the error above instead of a black screen.

Comment: I didn't realise I couldn't get into the BIOS of a Hyper-V System. I've never had to, as the config allows changing the settings I've needed. I'll edit my post to reflect. I do, however, believe it's easy enough to get an earlier version of VMM that may not understand what needs to be done to migrate from newer ESXi to newer Hyper-V. I've had my own issues in the past moving an old Server 2003 ESXi guest to Hyper-V 2012 R2 using VMM, and it had to do with dive config on the Hyper-V host. And, because it had multiple drives and was trying to boot to the wrong one, I saw no error on my console.

Comment: So I checked the settings, there are not SCSI controllers/drives.  I have one IDE drive configured, and it is set to boot IDE hard drive first.  I am looking for where the v1 vs v2 setting is now.

Comment: I can also confirm, if I change from IDE to SCSI for the hard drive I get a 'cant find boot device' type message, instead of the black screen with flashing cursor.